# Rename all nodes in a graph to a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using the NetworkX graph library for Python. At some point in my program I would like to "consolidate" my nodeIDs into a sequence of numbers. Here's my naive approach:

```
start = 1 # could be anything
for i, n in enumerate(g.nodes()):
    if i+start == n:
        continue
    g.add_node(i+start, attr_dict=g.node[n])
    g.add_edges_from([(i+start, v, g[n][v]) for v in g.neighbors(n)])
    g.remove_node(n)
```

Is there a faster way than this exhaustive copy of all the neighbors? For example, I tried `g[i+start] = g[n]`, but that is forbidden.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Would this work?

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_nodes_from('spam')
print G.nodes()
```

returns:

```
['a', 1, 's', 'm', 'p']
```

now:

```
start = 1
G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G,first_label=start)
print G.nodes()
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! That function does exactly what I asked. But unfortunately it's not in-place, so looking at the [source](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/browser/networkx/networkx/convert.py) (lines 214-357) it's still O(V+E) instead of the theoretically-possible O(V). Still, it looks like it's 25% faster than my attempt.

Comment: It just occurred to me that given the way graphs are implemented in networkx, the O(V) bound won't be attainable. Every edge will have to be visited to remap the nodeID.

Answer (score 10):

In case your interest is still relevant, there is [`networkx.relabel_nodes()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes) which takes a mapping dictionary.